# Iframe responsive

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-5

I have a website where I cant make the iframe responsive. The map looks properly in computer however the map is invisible in mobile phone. I am currently using bootstrap

```
<div class="container d-none d-sm-block mb-5 pb-4">
<div class="wrapper" id="map" style="height: 480px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d5994.821337674272!2d69.25345364107476!3d41.29992894681807!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x38ae8ae3e16117eb%3A0xe38bf57767a5d5a9!2z0KjQutC-0LvQsCDihJY5MQ!5e0!3m2!1sru!2s!4v1689872593583!5m2!1sru!2s"
            width="1100" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</div>
```

Maybe the problem is with bootstrap style so below are links and scripts:

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.png">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/magnific-popup.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/themify-icons.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/nice-select.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/flaticon.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/gijgo.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/animate.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/slicknav.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/style.css' %}">


<script src="{% static 'blog/js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/ajax-form.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.counterup.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/scrollIt.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/wow.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/nice-select.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/plugins.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/gijgo.min.js' %}"></script>

<!--contact js-->
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/contact.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.form.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.validate.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/mail-script.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'blog/js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: How can the iframe be responsive when it is fixed to `width="1100" height="450"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `d-none d-sm-block` on your main container.
It's Bootstrap for "this element starts with `display: none;` and only goes `display: block;` when the screen is 576px wide or more". If you need more clarification on what that means, you need to read CSS and Bootstrap documentation.

Comment: That worked! Just changed it to 'display:block'.